How much damage do Brawlers deal with Improvised Weapons?
Looking at the UA 2023 Playtest 7 article, one of the new Fighter subclasses introduced is the Brawler.
At 3rd level, they get a feature called Improvised Expert that enhances improvised weapons. However, it does not mention damage die, unlike the Unarmed Expert feature, which does explicitly mention the damage die you can use for unarmed strikes.
I'm only familiar with the old 5e rules, not "5.5e" rules (by which I mean the new 2024 stuff), so I would assume it is still the case that improvised weapons deal 1d4+STR damage like in 5e.
At level 15, they then get a feature called Improvised Specialist, which explicitly mentions that two-handed improvised weapons now use a d12 die. A jump from d4 to d12 seems quite dramatic, which further convinces me that I must have missed something.
Are there new improvised weapons rules that this subclass assumes that I should be aware of? Or is it really still just 1d4 like it used to be?

I haven't seen the "official" release of Brawler, so it might be that the official version clears up my confusion without having to find a different section of rules for improvised weapons. I'm happy either way, so long as I know what the damage die should be.

I’ve retagged this with the playtest tag, we decided not to use the unearthed arcana tag for one-dnd playtest material.

The tagging is confusing me a bit, would you be equally happy with a 2024 rules answer or are you specifically looking for UA playtest answers?

Either is fine, since AFAIK the UA playtest stuff was just proto-2024 rules anyway. The main thing was just seeing if they had updated the improv. weapons rules at all since the original 2014 PHB rules, in either that playtest or in the brand new 2024 rules.

Gotcha. Brawler didn't ultimately make it into the 2024 PHB so an answer would be more about whether the improvised weapons rules have changed. I don't think they have but can type up a more definitive answer later.

d4 damage (or damage of a similar weapon)
The playtest materials state on p. 1:

The material here the rules in the 2014 Player’s Handbook, except where noted.

As there is no note of the damage for improvised weapons being changed anywhere in the document, other than the level 15 Improvised Specialist feature you mention, that means improvised weapons deal the damage listed in the 2014 PHB, p. 147f:

In many cases, an improvised weapon is similar to an actual weapon and can be treated as such. For example, a table leg is akin to a club. At the DM’s option, a character proficient with a weapon can use a similar object as if it were that weapon and use his or her proficiency bonus.
An object that bears no resemblance to a weapon deals 1d4 damage (the DM assigns a damage type appropriate to the object).

That is, they deal the damage of a similar weapon, or 1d4.
For what it's worth, Improvised weapons for the 2024 rules are listed in the Rules Glossary (p. 369, PHB), which says:

Damage. On a hit, the weapon deals 1d4 damage of a type the DM thinks is appropriate for the object.
Weapon equivalents. If an improvised weapon resembles a Simple or Martial weapon, the DM may say it functions as that weapon and uses that weapon's rules. (...)

So, same same. The 2024 rules include Tavern Brawler as an Origin feat that you can access by choosing the Sailor background. It allows you to use your proficiency bonus on improvised weapons, but does not change their damage die either.


An object that bears no resemblance to a weapon deals 1d4 damage.

That does not include things that do resemble weapons. Guidance for that is 1 paragraph earlier:

Often, an improvised weapon is similiar to an actual weapon and can be treated as such.

So, DM can decide that table leg is similiar to mace and thus has 1d6 damage die. Improvised Specialist ensures that you get 1d12 die for 2h weapons without relying on DM Fiat.

I assume these quotes come from the original 5e rules? Or is it the case the "5.5e" rules use exactly the same wording?

@NathanS Quotes are from 5e 2014 rules. I do not know if either 5e 2024 or OneD&D uses different wording.

That was more what I was asking about. The question was originally tagged as [[tag:dnd-5e-2024]] but was then retagged, admittedly before you answered, so that may not have been as obvious after the retag (I've now added the word "new" to the question to hopefully make that a little clearer).

I was mostly responding to your assumption that "improvised weapons deal 1d4+STR damage like in 5e". That's not true in regards to 5e 2014.

Yeah, I was generalising, since as your answer points out, improv. weapons that resemble weapons could use different damage die.

The 5e ruleset is not the one-dnd-palaytest, therefore, -1

@Trish but the question is built on flawed assumption that 5e ruleset sets the die to d4.

@matszwecja You still don't quote the one-dnd-playtest document, or even source your quotations, which means your answer is at least badly cited, or at worst, totally wrong. You'd need to show first that the playtest did not set the die, then you could quote the provision that otherwise the 5e rule applies and only then you can quote the 5e rule.

Ând if you quote: Provide a page and which book.
